# Mostrar ocorrências como campos

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados, gostaria de saber se dá para agrupar elementos e exibi-los como se fossem campos e dentro desses campos a quantidade de ocorrências.

**ex:**
A tabela é assim:

```
nome_tarefa | data_criacao | status
-----------------------------------------
tarefa 1    | 12-02-2016   | pendente
tarefa 2    | 13-02-2016   | pendente
tarefa 3    | 13-02-2016   | concluida
```

após a consulta ficaria assim:

```
pendente| concluida | 
-----------------------------------------
2       | 1         |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente é isso:

```
SELECT
   SUM( IF( status='pendente' , 1, 0 ) ) AS pendente,
   SUM( IF( status='concluida', 1, 0 ) ) AS concluida
FROM
   tarefas
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45a29/1)**

Comment: Nossa, eu tava me matando aqui para lembrar de algum comando que fizesse isso, eu nunca ia sacar que era isso, muito obrigado.